# Transparent button with border

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, transparency

Im trying to get this effect with buttons that make them transparent, but still have a border. When i make transparent images they make the button bigger for some reason. Here are some examples of the effect.

[image: In this image the buttons on the navigation bar are semi-transparent to the background of the navigation bar.]

[image: On the left side the "Action Composer" button is transparent, but still has a border.]

In the first image the buttons on the navigation bar are semi-transparent to the background of the navigation bar.

In the second image on the left side the "Action Composer" button is transparent, but still has a border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one :

This will create a transparent button:

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame  GRectMake(x, y, w, h);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.1 blue:0.4 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Now for border :

```
[[button layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[button layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to create an image asset for the button.

The image will have a border and a clear middle.

Then use the image as the button image.

Comment: I second that. Create an image and use the `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` method to create scale9-grid images

Comment: Yes, stretchableImages is the way to go.

Comment: +1.  The images used in the screenshots are not actually transparent.

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend having a look at [FTWButton](https://github.com/FTW/FTWButton). It's a super customizable UIControl that replicates UIButton and offers an insane amount of versatility in terms of look. It also has some nice animation between control states.

It comes with some built in styles, but you can customize the button completely to your liking.

I don't have anything to do with the project, I just use it for one of my own projects and love it :)